# IService Constructor not Constructing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, constructor, repository

Sorry for the vague title. I'll explain what I'm trying to get working.

My Admin View uses an Admin ViewModel which in turn calls an Admin Service which is a collection of Admin Repositories. For the sake of simplicity lets say that there is only one repository referenced by the Admin Service.

When constructing my Admin View Model the top of my class looks like this

```
public class adminMenuVM
{
    private readonly IAdminMenuService menuService;

    public adminMenuVM(IAdminMenuService adminMenuService)
    {
        this.menuService = adminMenuService;
    }

    public adminMenuVM()
    {
        menuItems = getMenuItems();
        menuCats = getMenuCats();
    }
}
```

Where getMenuItems and getMenuCats are two methods that use the service to retrieve data which is then set for the view model.

My problem is that when I run the app I get the error "Object Reference not set to instance of an object". Now I know that this is because the adminMenuVM() is called by the viwModel and not the constructor initializing the service.

My question is how can I ensure that the service constructor is called and does its thing when my view model is called?

I've tried using :this on the parameterless constructor but it wont allow me to assign an interface since you can't create a new instance of an interface.

Edit @ 18:49
I've had a thought but don't know how to implement it. Can anyone advise on how I could "Constructor Chain" or if it is possible? My thought is to chain the parameterless constructor to service constructor this ensuring it gets called. I may be way off but would be grateful for yer help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure this one out. Its not the cleanest solution but I can't see any other way to do it. I'll stick this in to help anyone else who comes across this issue.

The issue boiled down to passing the current instance of the service interface to the ViewModel. The only place I could find that the instance was being set was the constructor of my controller. So very simply I declared a public global variable of the interface service type and saved the instance to that. The current instance persits and can be passed to the constructor of my viewmodel and satisfy the viewmodel constructors requirement. To clarify I've included an example of the controller and a viewmodel.

Controller:

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    private readonly IAdminMenuService lmService;
    public IAdminMenuService testService;

    public AdminController(IAdminMenuService layoutMarkupService)
    {
        this.lmService = layoutMarkupService;
        testService = lmService;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public PartialViewResult menuPartial()
    {
        return PartialView("_AdminMenuPartial", new adminMenuVM(testService));
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class adminMenuVM
{
    private readonly IAdminMenuService menuService;

    public adminMenuVM(IAdminMenuService AdminMenuService)
    {
        this.menuService = AdminMenuService;
        menuItems = getMenuItems();
        menuCats = getMenuCats();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first constructor looks like it should be used by some Dependency Injection container.

You can use just one constructor to create an instance. When that DI creates an instance with a supplied "IAdminMenuService", then you can create a new instance by using the second constructor, but as that's a new instance, the "menuService" will be empty (null).

You will need to find out how to get tan instance of your adminMenuVM from the DI container (if that is what you use).

Comment: Yes I am using DI, sorry should have mentioned that but thought that the issue was at the level of my ViewModel. Could I register the adminMenuVM against the IAdminMenuService in the gloabal.asax file as such .RegisterType<IAdminMenuService, adminMenuVM>(new HttpContextLifetimeManager<IAdminMenuService>()).

Comment: Scratch that, doesn't work in global.asax. You've given me some food for thought though.

Answer (score 0):

Remove that default constructor and put its contents into the constructor with the parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Tried that already and still the same error. I'm assuming this is due to the constructor requiring a variable of type IAdminMenuService which I can't set

Comment: Is the instance of adminMenuVM created by you or by the mvc framework? Also, please show me, how you tried it, because you shouldn't get *the same* error!

Comment: Its created by MVC Framework when I create a strongly typed view against my VM. This is what is at the top of my VM @model GenericCMS.ViewModels.adminMenuVM

Comment: Hm, sorry, I don't know the ASP.NET MVC framework, so I am not able to further help you :(

Comment: No worries, hopefully someone else can. Thanks for taking a stab at it anyway. It may be worth noting that the same issue occurs if I'm trying to construct the service from a regular class